# Definition of the conditional expectation operator $E^Q_{t,z}$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, expected-value

I'm studying the book "Arbitrage Theory in Continuous Time" by Bjork, and the authore uses a lot the notation $E^Q_{t,z}$, where $Q$ is a probability measure and $z=Z_t$ a stochastic process, but he did not give the definition.

Form the exercise below (taken from the book) I guess that $E^Q_{t,z}(Z_u)=E^Q(Z_u|Z_t)$. So for $u = t$ we should have $E^Q_{t,z}(Z_u)=Z_t$, is this correct?

[image]

Comment: $E^Q_{t,z}$ must be $E^Q(\cdot|Z_t=z)$. But that doesn't mean $E^Q_{t,z}(Z_u)=Z_t$, which would be true if $Z$ were also a martingale. In any case, are you sure there's no definition in the book? I'd have another look at the section where the author first discusses Markov processes.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. So in the exercise $$\int_t^T d\log Z_t^2=\log Z_T^2-\log Z_t^2,$$ but then $$E^Q_{t,z}(\log Z_t^2)=E^Q(\log Z_t^2|Z_t=z)=\log z^2?$$

Comment: Sure. And yes, that's correct.

Comment: Ok thanks. To be rigorous, in the integral should I change the time letter of $Z$, i.e. writing $\int_t^T d\log Z_s^2$ (with $s$ instead of $t$) ?

Comment: Yes. More like to be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation $\mathbb E^Q_{s,a}\big[B_t\big]$, where $B$ a stochastic process, $Q$ is the probability measure, $s\in\mathbb R^+$ a given time, $a\in\mathbb R$ a given value for the process $B$, is a shortcut for the longer notation for the conditional expectation of the stochastic process $\mathbb E^Q\big[B_t|B_s=a\big]$.

If the two times coincide, i.e. $t\equiv s$, then the result is:
 $$\mathbb E^Q_{s,a}\big[B_s\big]= \mathbb E^Q\big[B_s|B_s=a\big]=a.$$

Comment: You can find more about the notation here: https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~fewster/325/notes/ch3.pdf